# ¿Cómo implementar configuración de react-app-rewired a un proyecto de Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, next.js

Soy bastante nuevo en cuanto al tema de diseño y estilos con **React**, actualmente se me encargo obtener el componente de un **Template** que se compró, dicho componente se agregará a un proyecto realizado con **`Nextjs`**.

Se importan los archivos sin problemas pero parece no aplicarlos al componente que estoy sacando del template

Después de realizar varias pruebas, me doy cuenta de que el componente se muestra correctamente si en el `package.json` del template tiene la siguiente línea `react-app-rewired start` dentro de `scripts`, que parece que viene de la mano con el paquete `react-app-rewired`

Actualmente mi proyecto de `nextjs` se ejecuta con el siguiente comando `npm run dev`,

**¿Cómo puedo pasar la configuración del template al projecto de `Nextjs`?**

El contenido del archivo `config-overrides` que según la documentación del paquete `react-app-rewired` es donde va la configuración para el funcionamiento del template.

```
// Overriding CreateReactApp settings, ref: https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra
const {
  override,
  // fixBabelImports,
  addLessLoader,
  useEslintRc,
  addDecoratorsLegacy,
  useBabelRc,
} = require('customize-cra')

// eslint config
const eslintConfig = require('./.eslintrc.js');
const useEslintConfig = configRules => config => {
  const updatedRules = config.module.rules.map(
    rule => {
      // Only target rules that have defined a `useEslintrc` parameter in their options
      if (rule.use && rule.use.some(use => use.options && use.options.useEslintrc !== void 0)) {
        const ruleUse = rule.use[0]
        const baseOptions = ruleUse.options
        const baseConfig = baseOptions.baseConfig || {}
        const newOptions = {
          useEslintrc: false,
          ignore: true,
          baseConfig: { ...baseConfig, ...configRules },
        }
        ruleUse.options = newOptions
        return rule

        // Rule not using eslint. Do not modify.
      } else {
        return rule
      }
    }
  )

  config.module.rules = updatedRules;
  return config;
}

module.exports = override(
  addDecoratorsLegacy(),
  useEslintRc(),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  }),
  useEslintConfig(eslintConfig),
  useBabelRc(),
)
```

Dicha configuración parece que se tendría que pasar al proyecto de `Nextjs` que me parece que va en el archivo de `next.config.js` que solo tiene lo siguiente, ya que soy bastante nuevo en **React** y **Nextjs** es el único lugar donde me parece que puede ir dicha configuración por lo tanto lo intenté adaptar de la única manera que se me ocurrió, quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
const path = require('path')


// eslint config
const eslintConfig = require('./.eslintrc.js');
const useEslintConfig = configRules => config => {
  const updatedRules = config.module.rules.map(
    rule => {
      // Only target rules that have defined a `useEslintrc` parameter in their options 
        return rule
      
    }
  )

  config.module.rules = updatedRules;
  return config;
}


module.exports = {
  webpack: useEslintConfig(eslintConfig),
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
  
}
```

Dicha configuración ahora me manda el siguiente error en la interfaz pero no en consola

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: _ref.location is undefined

webpack\bootstrap (150:0) @ fn

  148 |                 hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |             }
> 150 |             return __webpack_require__(request);
  151 |         };
  152 |         var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |             return {
```

De igual manera el tema no se aplica al componente si en el `html` no contiene el siguiente atributo `data-kit-theme="dark"` quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
<html lang="en" data-kit-theme="dark">
```

Me gustaría que funcione sin eso, pero lo que mas importa es que funcione.

Comment: Hay un fichero que se incluye aquí: `const eslintConfig = require('./.eslintrc.js');
`. Creo que tiene contenido relevante para su pregunta.

Comment: Parece que el paquete depende de [`customize-cra`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra), que, a su vez, depende de `react-app-rewired`. Puedo intentar ayudarle con esto, pero la mejor opción sería pedirle al desarrollador que le haga un componente compatible con la configuración que usa usted de Nextjs.

Comment: @emi Si de hecho ya tengo dicho archivo de configuración he realizado varias pruebas, pero no logro hacer que funcione el componente en `Nextjs` justamente por la configuración de `react-app-rewired`, podría solicitar a quien compro dicho template que envíe mensajes a los desarrolladores a ver si aceptan dicha petición  o brinden alguna configuración para su uso en `Nextjs`

Answer (score 0):

`react-app-rewired` sirve para modificar configuraciones de Webpack que Create React App no permite modificar por defecto. Usted debería comprobar qué configuraciones se modifican y ver cómo hacer lo mismo con Next.js. El mismo creador de `react-app-rewired` [dice en su repositorio](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) que usa Next.js, así que probablemente podrá hacerlo sin demasiado problema.

Comment: Si, he revisado e intentado implementarlo pero no me reconoce el comando de ejecución `npm start`, solo `npm run dev` para iniciar el projecto de `nextjs`, pero no se como cambiar dicha configuración.

Comment: He cambiado mi pregunta al igual que he agregado nueva información basada en la investigación y pruebas que he estado realizando.

Answer (score 0):

De momento lo que me funciono fue modificar `next.config.js` e implementar la configuración del proyecto, realizando unos pequeños cambios. quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
const path = require("path");

// eslint config
const eslintConfig = require("./.eslintrc.js");
const useEslintConfig = configRules => config => {
  const updatedRules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
    return rule;
  });
  config.module.rules = updatedRules;
  return config;
};

module.exports = {
  webpack: useEslintConfig(eslintConfig),
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true
  },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")]
  }
};
```

teniendo lo siguiente en el archivo `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ["react-app", "airbnb", "prettier"],
  rules: {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    ],
    "no-useless-escape": "off",
    "no-script-url": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off",
    "no-template-curly-in-string": "off",
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
    "react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": 0,
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "react/jsx-wrap-multilines": 0,
    "react/no-danger": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "no-console": 0,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 0
    // "no-unused-vars": 0
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      legacyDecorators: true
    }
  }
};
```